# How to show reply form beneath its own review when reply is clicked

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have developed a review form using reactjs. I have used react-redux form for that. The review is working fine. But there is a reply button in each review for replying to the specific review. 
I can get a reply form either at the bottom or in all the review but that is not what i want.

How can i show a reply form just beneath a review whose reply button is clicked?

**my code**

```
class PostReview extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { reviewByUser: [], wantToReply: false }
        this.handleReplySubmit = this.handleReplySubmit.bind(this);
    }
    loadReviewFromServer(){
        axios({
            method:'GET',
            url:`/api/restaurant/${this.props.data.slug}`
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                reviewByUser:response.data.review
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadReviewFromServer();
    }
    onSubmit(props){
        axios({
            method:'POST',
            url:`/api/review/create/?type=restaurant&slug=${this.props.data.slug}`,
            headers:{
                'X-CSRFToken':CSRF_TOKEN,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            data:{
                review:props.review
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.loadReviewFromServer();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            throw("Error: ",error);
        });
    }

    handleReplySubmit(event){
        console.log(event.target)
        // const id = $(event.target).data("review-click-id");
        this.setState({
            wantToReply:!this.state.wantToReply
        });
    }


    renderAllReview(){
        return _.map(this.state.reviewByUser, (review) => {
            return (
                <div className="contents" key={review.id}> 
                    <a className="author">{ review.reviewer }</a>
                    <div className="metadata">
                        <span className="date">Today at 5:42PM</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="text">
                        { review.review }
                    </div>
                    <div className="actions">
                        <a className="reply" data-review-click-id={review.id} onClick={this.handleReplySubmit}>Reply</a>
                    </div>
                   {this.renderAllReply(review)}

                </div>
                )
        });
    }

    renderAllReply(review){
        return _.map(review.children, (reply) => {
            return(
                     <div className="content" key={reply.id}>
                              <a className="author">{reply.reviewer}</a>
                              <div className="metadata">
                                <span className="date">Just now</span>
                              </div>
                              <div className="text">
                                {reply.review}
                              </div>
                      </div>
                )
        })
    }
    render(){
    const { fields : { review }, handleSubmit } = this.props; 
    return(
        <div className="review-section">
            <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(props => this.onSubmit(props))} className="form-inline">
                <div className={`form-group ${review.touched && review.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ' ' }`}>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" {...review} />
                    <div className="text-help">
                        {review.touched ? review.error : '' }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn tomato">Pen your review</button>
            </form>
            <div className="all-reviews">
                <div className="ui comments">
                    <h3 className="ui dividing header">Reviews</h3>
                    <div className="comment">
                        <div className="content">
                            { this.renderAllReview() }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    }
}

function validate(values){
    const errors = {};

    if(!values.review){
        errors.review = 'Enter Review'; 
    }
    return errors;
}

export default reduxForm({
    form:'PostReview',
    fields:['review'],
    validate
})(PostReview)
```

;

[image]

I want only a reply box for the review not for the replies.